# Google Analytics Page Value coming not set

Tags: android, google-analytics

Hi I have added analytics with custom dimensions everything is working fine but value for Page field is not coming.
I have also added image from analytics
Below is the Code I have written
[Analytics Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fEnm.png)

```
 Tracker t = ((ApplicationClass) LoginActivity.this.getApplication()).getTracker();
    t.setScreenName("/SYED");
    t.setPage("/123Fuzail");
    t.setTitle("/123Title");
    t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
            .setCustomDimension(1,"6199")
            .setCustomDimension(2,"999")
            .setCustomDimension(3, "Syed fuzail")
            .build()
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a goal configured with a value (and the user reached it in the session) or there are no transactions in the session (that visited those pages) that value remains 0.

> Page Value is the average value for a page that a user visited before landing on the goal page or completing an Ecommerce transaction (or both). This value is intended to give you an idea of which page in your site contributed more to your site's revenue. If the page wasn't involved in an ecommerce transaction for your website in any way, then the Page Value for that page will be $0 since the page was never visited in a session where a transaction occurred.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2695658?hl=en